# Регулярное выражение для исключения урла соц сети

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с написанием регулярного выражения. Для начала нужно было составить регулярное выражение которое пропускало бы ссылки только на соц сети: вк, facebook, instagram. В результате получил такое выражение, которое вполне вполне подходит под поставленную задачу. Для других соц сетей, регулярки аналогичный.

`^https?:\/\/vk\.com\/(.+)\/?$`

Но потом возникла задача, нужно сделать фильтр который будет пропускать ссылки (данное условие можно пропустить, оно идет отдельным правилом в фильтре) но при этом не будет пропускать ссылки на указанные выше социальные сети. Я попытался использовать lookahead-выражение, но что то результат совсем не тот что я ожидаю. Может кто объяснить как правильно писать регулярные выражение под подобную задачу.

Comment: `^https?:\/\/(?!(?:linkedin\.com|yahoo\.com)(?:\/|$))vk\.com\/(.+)`?

Comment: А можете объяснить момент именно с использованием `?:` А то не могу понять  этот момент

Comment: `(?:linkedin\.com|yahoo\.com)` - `linkedin.com` или `yahoo.com`

Comment: Ага, вроде как понял, вот такой пример: `^https?:\/\/(?!(?:vk\.com|youtube\.com|facebook\.com|instagram\.com)(?:\/|$))(.+)` будет пропускать все ссылки кроме тех что начинаются на указанные сайты социальных сетей